# How can I best filter and sort DataGridViews whose source is a Linq to SQL query?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm in the middle of refactoring a WinForms application that uses DataSets and DataTables. I am trying to move the data to ADO.NET Entities.

I'm at a point where I have my entities in my data sources window, and can drag them onto various `DataGridViews`. The `BindingSources` are automatically created. Then, in the code behind I set the data source:

```
Dim context = New Entities()
CompanyBindingSource.DataSource = context.companies.toList()
```

The problem is that a Linq to SQL query result is not a Sortable or Filterable binding source, so the sorting on the DGVs doesn't work; and I also can't set filters on the `BindingSources`.

I came across [this project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blw/) and various other solutions which helps with some of this. They basically wrap the Linq query in a sortable list:

```
CompanyBindingSource.DataSource = BindingListView(Of company)(context.companies.toList())
```

and the DGV for companies works. But the problem is, the related entities (for example in my case, the list of company's contracts) are not wrapped in this way, and so their respective DGV's are still not sortable or filterable.

I want to make sure I'm not missing something before I go through and manually create all the binding sources and set their data source property. The drag-and-drop binding is super convenient and is used extensively throughout the project, so this would save a huge amount of time.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You surely have to wrap the query result in something supporting sorting and filtering such as `BindingSource`, ... Or re-execute your query each time (with modified OrderBy, Where) you want to sort, filter the source

Comment: But say I have 5 related parent-child entities. Currently I can drag-and-drop to the DGVs. But there's no way to add filtering or sorting to, say, the 3rd child? For that I have to implement all the `BindingSources` and key relationships myself, thereby losing all the designer's functionality in customizing the DGVs?

Comment: So basically, if you want to filter a child DGV, you can't use the designer to do data bindings. Is that accurate?

Comment: I'm not sure, in fact I've rarely used designer, just code manually, I think there must be some solution, just wait for others, sometimes an answer can be added in even 3 days since the time the question has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with involves partial classes. Say I have a `company` that has many `contracts`. If I just dragged the relationship from the Data Sources panel, the `contracts` wouldn't be sortable in my DGV. But I can just use partial classes for my `company` and add my own collection:

```
Partial Public Class Company

    Public ReadOnly Property visibleContracts As SortableBindingList(Of contract)
        Get
            Dim list = New SortableBindingList(Of contract)

            For Each c As contract In contracts.ToList
                list.Add(c)
            Next

            Return list
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Now my DGV can bind to `visibleContracts`, and the designer takes care of all the syncing up - but now the DGV is sortable!